# Giving permission to a folder in programdata using Wix

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I have created a folder in ProgramData. Now, I want to give full permission to everyone. How do I do that using WiX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272406/wix-how-to-set-permissions-for-folder-and-all-sub-folders or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149822/how-to-set-folder-permissions-on-install-in-a-localizable-fashion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under `<Product>` you can enter:

```
   <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="CommonAppXXXX" Name="XXXFolderName">
            <Component Id="CreateProgramDataZZZ" Guid="ABC-ETC">
              <CreateFolder>
                <util:PermissionEx User="Users" Domain="[MachineName]" GenericAll="yes" />
              </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

And reference the component in your `feature`.

Comment: what's the `util` namespace defined as?